# Rewrite Rules in Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

New to htaccess: how can i write rewrite Rules for this,
instead of http://www.x.com/directory.php?state=TX have www.x.com/texas-fishing
instead of http://www.x.com/directory.php?state=WA have www.x.com/washington-fishing

Actually $1 indicates the dynamic part of the Url like(TX,WA..), but here i need complete title of the page. So do i need to modify in script or .htaccess is enough to manage.
If it is enough then how can we manage..

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^texas-fishing$ directory.php?state=TX  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^washington-fishing$ directory.php?state=WA  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your response...Actually Based on the id i want to display the page title but i want to hide the id from the url instead of this http://X.com/Test-Blog/466 have http://X.com/Test-Blog/ .     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /view-blog.php?blog_title=$1&blog_id=$2         i have used this.. for that